# Scraping an infinite-scroll webpage for images with Puppeteer but returning nothing within await async

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, async-await, puppeteer

So I'm using node.js and Puppeteer to try to scrape a certain number of image URLs from an infinitely-scrolling webpage (I'm just using the reddit homepage to test, but substitute in your own if you want), but the array that's supposed to hold them is coming back empty.

I even put it all in an anonymous async function so I could force it to `await`, in case timing was the problem:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

var pBrowser = await puppeteer.launch();
console.log("\t* Browser launched");
var pPage       = await pBrowser.newPage();
console.log("\t* Page launched");

let sUrl = foo;
await pPage.goto(sUrl);

let iItemCount = 10;
let tImageSrcs = [];
await async function () {
    let iPreviousHeight;
    console.log("Starting search at the top");
    while (tImageSrcs.length < iItemCount) {
        tImageSrcs = await pPage.evaluate( function() {
            let tItems = Array.from(document.images, e => e.src );
            console.log("\t\t* "+tItems.length+" images overall found within this section; trimming...");
            tItems = tItems.filter( sImage => [".jpg",".png"].includes(sImage.substring(sImage.length-4)) );
            console.log("\t\t* "+tItems.length+" images after filtering");
            return tImageSrcs.concat(tItems);
        });
        console.log("\t* "+tImageSrcs.length+" appropriate images sourced so far...");
        iPreviousHeight = await pPage.evalutate("document.body.scrollHeight");
        await pPage.evaluate('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)');
        console.log("Searching at scroll height "+iPreviousHeight);
        await pPage.waitForFunction(`document.body.scrollHeight > ${iPreviousHeight}`);
        await page.waitFor(1000);
    }
};
console.log("\t* "+tImageSrcs.length+" images sourced");
```

But it seems like it's not even calling *anything* in the async function because regardless of whether it was able to find any images or not, the output doesn't even contain *any* of the `console.log` statements, including the one at (almost) the very top of the async function:

```
        * Browser launched
        * Page launched
        * 0 images sourced
```

Comment: "await async function ()"  Is this way to use async/await?Please go through the docs how to use async/await.

Answer (score 1):

Some notes:

1. You create async function, but you do not call it, so it is not executed:

```js
await async function () { /*...*/ }
```

should be:

```js
await async function () { /*...*/ }()
```

2. Anyway, this wrapper function is redundant: I suppose you already are inside an async function as you use `await`, so there is no need to use a wrapper.
3. You call `console.log("\t* "+tImageSrcs.length+" images sourced");` when `tImageSrcs` is still empty as the function above is not executed (`await` just wait its creation, not execution).
4. `tImageSrcs` inside `pPage.evaluate()` code is not defined (`tImageSrcs` is a variable in the Node.js context, it is not available in the browser context). You need to tranfer it by its serializable value.

So try this variant:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

var pBrowser = await puppeteer.launch();
console.log("\t* Browser launched");
var pPage       = await pBrowser.newPage();
console.log("\t* Page launched");

let sUrl = foo;
await pPage.goto(sUrl);

let iItemCount = 10;
let tImageSrcs = [];

let iPreviousHeight;
console.log("Starting search at the top");

while (tImageSrcs.length < iItemCount) {
    tImageSrcs = await pPage.evaluate( function(srcs) {
        let tItems = Array.from(document.images, e => e.src );
        console.log("\t\t* "+tItems.length+" images overall found within this section; trimming...");
        tItems = tItems.filter( sImage => [".jpg",".png"].includes(sImage.substring(sImage.length-4)) );
        console.log("\t\t* "+tItems.length+" images after filtering");
        return srcs.concat(tItems);
    }, tImageSrcs);
    console.log("\t* "+tImageSrcs.length+" appropriate images sourced so far...");
    iPreviousHeight = await pPage.evalutate("document.body.scrollHeight");
    await pPage.evaluate('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)');
    console.log("Searching at scroll height "+iPreviousHeight);
    await pPage.waitForFunction(`document.body.scrollHeight > ${iPreviousHeight}`);
    await page.waitFor(1000);
}

console.log("\t* "+tImageSrcs.length+" images sourced");
```